# Prevent sharing of a java library

Tags: java, security, obfuscation

*I have a java library (.jar) that i would like to sell. I thought about creating some RSA keys to prevent sharing.*

*The problem is that, once someone buys my library, they could decompile, remove the "**security access thing**" and share the code.*

*My question is, how can I secure my library to prevent sharing. If that's not possible, how can I make it harder to be shared? Should I use some kind of **obfuscation**?*

Comment: You can't. DRM doesn't work. And you're likely overestimating the value of your library.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Pretty rude the last part tho..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options really.

1. Put the logic behind a web service and charge access to that service
2. Give your jar away and sell a license that the library would check

Obviously once the byte code is the wild there is really nothing you can do for the truly motivated individual but in practice license checks are "good enough" for commercial use.

If someone is pirating your library, that's a good sign you have something worth selling but it's overpriced or too hard to access for your market.

Comment: Can you explain me a little bit the license part?

Comment: That has been discussed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548510/how-to-create-license-for-my-java-software